# Is style a module of matplotlib or matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: matplotlib

Reading the matplotlib documentation, it looks like style is a module of matplotlib (matplotlib.style).

However, I've seen this code:
matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('seaborn')

I don't understand how the style module can be associated with (and called from) the matplotlib.pyplot module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib has a module `style`. This can be imported like

```
from matplotlib import style
```

The above line is also present inside the `pyplot.py`.
**`style` is thus in the namespace of `pyplot`** and you can do

```
matplotlib.pyplot.style.use("some_style")
```

Comment: Thanks! In the language of object-oriented programming, does this mean that importing the `style` module in `matplotlib.pyplot` makes `style` an attribute of `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Comment: Since pyplot is not a class, `style` cannot be an attribute. It is still a (sub)module. This submodule is in the namespace of pyplot.